# How do I get cause of Aggregte Exception in Service Fabric?

Tags: azure-service-fabric, service-fabric-stateful

I am getting an Aggregate exception when deploying a guest application into my local cluster

Unfortunately the error message is useless

```
2>Test-ServiceFabricApplicationPackage : One or more errors occurred.
2>At C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Service 
2>Fabric\Tools\PSModule\ServiceFabricSDK\Publish-UpgradedServiceFabricApplication.ps1:135 char:38
2>+ ... nSuccess = (Test-ServiceFabricApplicationPackage $AppPkgPathToUse -Im ...
2>+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
2>    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Test-ServiceFabricApplicationPackage], AggregateException
2>    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : TestApplicationPackageErrorId,Microsoft.ServiceFabric.Powershell.TestApplicationPackage
```

How do I get more information to see the exact cause of this?

I am deploying using Visual Studios publish

Paul

Comment: What does the inner exception say?

Comment: I cant see it thats the problem